# Can we use tritium instead of helium-3 for nuclear fusion reactors?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, nuclear-engineering, isotopes

I know that tritium isn't entirely stable (half-life of about 12.3 years) and might require a lot of energy to create large amounts (and transport/handle safely), but wouldn't that still be easier (and more sustainable) than searching for and mining He-3?

EDIT:    I wasn't clear.... Sorry...., Can we use ONLY tritium (and other easy-to-obtain - and cheap) materials in fusion reactors?  Leaving out helium-3 entirely?

I guess I'm having a hard time understanding why some (maybe only a few, but still) fusion researchers are so eager to pursue helium-3 option(s) when fusion is going to be expensive enough as it is, without mining the moon, or whatever....

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, we do use deuterium and tritium as fusion reactor fuel.

Comment: If you have Tritium, you will have Helium-3. All you need to do is wait; it's the decay product, and the main way Helium-3 is [produced industrially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium-3#Tritium_decay) today.

Comment: Also, it appears that Tritium (at \$30 000/g) is more than 20 times the cost per unit mass of $^3\mathrm{He}$ at ($1 400/g) currently.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "pick your poison" situation.

The problem with helium-3 is that naturally-occurring helium is a non-renewable resource, and helium-3 is a tiny fraction of it.

The problem with tritium is that it basically doesn't occur in nature at all. With a lifetime of only twelve years, any process that consumes tritium needs a continuous source of neutrons that you can put onto (heavy) hydrogen.  I guess this happens in nature, rarely, when neutrons produced from cosmic-ray spallation find deuterium. But most deuterium in nature is a trace contaminant in hydrogen chemistry.  One confirmation:

> Before [the era of] nuclear tests, there were only about 3 to 4 kilograms of tritium on the Earth's surface; but these amounts rose by 2 or 3 orders of magnitude during the post-test period.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritium), citing [Jenkins and Smethie](https://www.whoi.edu/oceanus/feature/transient-tracers-track-ocean-cimate-signals/?id=2330).

It's probably *possible* to engineer a helium-3-free fusion cycle. However, helium-3 has useful neutron interaction properties, and it'll be produced spontaneously in any unspent tritium fuel by beta decay, so there's probably no reason to ignore it completely.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, helium 3 is just aged tritium. Tritium is most economically made by replacing some control rods in ordinary fission reactors with lithium-6 or boron rods. This was done for years [to make tritium for nuclear weapons](https://www.nrc.gov/docs/ML0325/ML032521359.pdf). There is no need for anything as exotic as fusion to make all the tritium anyone can want, half of which turns to helium 3 in just 12 yeqrs.